# Debugging protractor test in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, protractor, gulp-protractor

I have project and I use protractor test. But I would like use debugging but I don't know how to create config for him.
It is my **protractor.conf.js**

```
'use strict';

var paths = require('./.yo-rc.json')['generator-gulp-angular'].props.paths;

exports.config = {
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  specs: [paths.e2e + '/**/*.js'],

  mochaOpts: {
    timeout: 5000
  },

  framework: 'mocha'
};
```

And **e2e-tests.js** gulp file:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

module.exports = function(options) {
  gulp.task('webdriver-update', $.protractor.webdriver_update);

  gulp.task('webdriver-standalone', $.protractor.webdriver_standalone);

  function runProtractor (done) {

    gulp.src(options.e2e + '/**/**.js')
      .pipe($.protractor.protractor({
        configFile: 'protractor.conf.js'
      }))
      .on('error', function (err) {
        // Make sure failed tests cause gulp to exit non-zero
        throw err;
      })
      .on('end', function () {
        // Close browser sync server
        browserSync.exit();
        done();
      });
  }

  gulp.task('protractor', ['protractor:src']);
  gulp.task('protractor:src', ['serve:e2e', 'webdriver-update'], runProtractor);
  gulp.task('protractor:dist', ['serve:e2e-dist', 'webdriver-update'], runProtractor);
};
```

Help me please fix this issue because write code without quick watch and other good components not very well.